# "throw" a warning in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

In FireFox, there is this cute little Error-Console [Ctrl+Shift+J] where I can add an error by throwing it from JavaScript. Is there a way to display a warning or a message, too? I dont mean `console.warn()`, i really want it in the error-console, i'd just prefer to have it a warning mark instead of an error marking.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this for a webpage or a Firefox plugin?

Comment: If you've got Firebug installed there's a `console.warn()`.

Comment: webpage. @Pointy: did u read my question…?

Comment: Ah OK, sorry.  I misunderstood what you meant by that reference to `console.warn()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Warning in JavaScript. All errors are fatal.

`console.warn` will, in browsers that implement it, print a warning-level message in the console (similar to malformed HTML or security warnings).

Personally, I'd just write `console.log("Warning: It's late and I'm drunk.");`

Comment: hmm, thats what i just tried, but it gets added only to the Web-Console [Strg+Shift+K], not to the error console.

Comment: @rhavin: I really think the error console is mostly for internal code. You can write to that console from a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a number of built-in error constructors, such as `Error()`, `SyntaxError()`, and `TypeError()`, and others, which are used with the `throw` statement. These objects contain interesting information about the error such as the name property of the constructor function that created the object, or the message that was passed in to the object.

The fun part about JavaScript is that you can throw any objects you want. So based on this concept, you can do something like `throw {name: "some name", message: "some message", remedy: callback}`, catch this error in a top level `try/catch` statement and output the contents using `console.log`.

Hope this helps.